# How to get the background image of a button control in Xamarin Android c#?

Tags: c#, android, button, background-image, code-behind

I am using a button control. I want get the **android:background** (image source) from code behind. Based on that I will continue with my code.
How can I get the image source from code behind?

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnPlayPause"
android:layout_width="34dp"
android:layout_height="34dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:background="@drawable/play"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Button btn = new Button(Context);
Drawable btnDrawable = btn.Background;
```

now you can compare the drawable with others (for example from Android.Resource)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
var beachImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };

btnPlayPause.Image = ImageSource.FromFile("imageName.png");
```

Comment: I want to get/fetch the background image. not set the image to the button.